# Use another author.php if different multisite subsite?

Tags: multisite, templates, author

I have a multisite installation with 2 subsites (site A, site B) using same theme.
Is it possible to use a different author.php if Im on the site B? Assuming the second author template exists.

For exeample..

```
if (blog_id == 2){
// use this template
diff-author-template.php
}
else {
//use this
author.php}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about [the file that your theme uses for its author pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#author-display)? If so, you can use the [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter to select a different template file.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I hadn't used that template tag before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the solution..

```
// different author template */
add_filter( 'template_include', 'author_template', 99 );

function author_template( $template ) {
    if( !is_main_site() and is_author( ) ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'other-author.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```